# Is there a GUI debugger for shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, debugging

Debugging bash scripts on command line is complicated.

Is there a good GUI based debugger available for debugging bash scripts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download [ShellEd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/) eclipse plugin (update site didn't work for me) which allows editing bash scripts. Install this via `Help -> Install new software -> Add -> Archive`.

Download [basheclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/basheclipse/) and extract the contents to your eclipse `plugins` directory plugin.

Restart eclipse. Create a new Eclipse project `BashTest`.

Add a file `myscript.sh` to the project:

```
#! /bin/bash

. _DEBUG.sh

echo 'kshitiz'
echo 'This is a test'
x=1
y=3
z=3
```

Add `_DEBUG.sh` to your project (Its in the downloaded zip for `basheclipse`).

Go to `Run -> Debug configurations` and create a new configuration under `Bash script` category. Select `myscript.sh`.

[image]

Then click `Debug`. Open `Debug` perspective.

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Shell script -> Interpreters` and ensure that interpreter is `/bin/bash`. For me the default was `/bin/dash`.

[image]

Set a breakpoint in the script. For some reason the right click menu does not show the option to set the breakpoint but `Ctrl+Shift+B` should work.
[image]

Run the script `Run -> Run as -> Run shell script`.  The breakpoint will hit but it won't be able to find your script source (wierd eh!). Just click `Select Bash script` and select `myscript.sh`.

Now you can step through the code and analyze the variables:
[image]

Comment: `Just click Select Bash script and select myscript.sh` what is it mean where to select?Is it Run > Rus As or Debug > Debug As?In my case break points are not hitting.

Comment: @Chandrayya G K : this is located in the debug perspective

Answer (score 2):

If you are a GNU Emacs user, you can use the emacs-package [realgud](https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr/wiki).