# Is there a GUI debugger for csh script?

Tags: shell, shell-script, debugging, csh

I have read [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131491/is-there-a-gui-debugger-for-shell-scripts) in UNIX & LINUX stack exchange. The GUI provided in that question can be used to bebug *.sh file. How about to debug *.csh file? What other plugins for eclipse can I use so that I can debug the <*.csh> files?

Answer (score 1):

You are unlikely to find such a tool, as `csh` is widely viewed to be [inappropriate for shell scripting](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). If you have any Bourne-derived shells available to you (e.g. `sh`, `ksh`, `mksh`, `ash`, `dash`, `bash`), you should consider reimplementing your work in one of those, or use a more complete scripting language such as Awk or Perl. You'll find far more robust tools for any of those alternatives, as well as more people who are knowledgeable about them who can assist you.

If you have no choice but to use `csh` (e.g. vendor-supplied script), it has some command-line options that may help to give you a better idea of what's going on:

- `-n` -- causes commands to be parsed, but not executed; useful for checking syntax of `csh` constructs
- `-v` -- sets the `verbose` variable to be set, which causes input commands to be echoed before variable substitution and before actual execution
- `-x` -- sets the `echo` variable, which is similar to `-v`/`verbose`, but it echoes the commands after substitution

For example, to check the syntax of `myscript.csh`:

```
prompt% csh -n myscript.csh
```

If your script is executable, you can force one or more options on the first line of the script:

```
#!/path/to/csh -vx
```

However, since these are runtime options, they may be of limited use to you within Eclipse.